# C++ and LuaJIT, Scoped script environment

Tags: c++, luajit

I've been using LuaJIT for some times now. The tip of the iceberg was enought for my needs until now, but my recent project require me to dig a little deeper.

My actual knowledge of LuaJIT is making function available from C++ to Lua and from Lua to C++. That include passing parameters, tables and retrieving return values.

This is the model I am used to:

[image: This is the model I am used to.]

I tried to search around for "scoped environement luajit" and multiple variation of the query, but unfortunately I did not find anything relevant. I might not use the right words?

This is the model I want to achieve :

[image: This is the model I want to achieve.]

I want to make a "global script environment" that I will share the C++ functions with then make it available to the "scoped script environments".

```
//push arguments
luaScopedEnvironment1->call("doSomething");
```

I just want a starting point, help for the terminology and maybe some pointers to related documentation :)

Thanks you for taking time to read me.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think Lua or LuaJIT supports such a thing but if I'm not mistaken, what you are after is called "sandboxing".

It creates a new environment with which you can strip out or add functionality to. Its handy for removing IO and OS functionality.